Can a salesforce record's data be changed without changing the systemmodstamp?
We pull data using the Salesforce Rest API. This data pull is performed incrementally using the systemmodstamp as the watermark column. Our assumption is that any change to a non-formula field or lookup field will result in the systemmodstamp being updated.
Recently we found an example where a Salesforce record had a column value change, but the systemmodstamp did not change. Because our system pulls using an automated script, the data didnt seem to have changed upto about an hour since we last pulled it. But when we manually ran the script/look at the data in Salesforce the field's value is different, but the systemodstamp did not change. The only way this seems to make sense is that if one can update a value in such a way that Salesforce doesnt update the SystemModStamp. Is this possible?

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/312774/why-is-systemmodstamp-missing-updates is a good read. Also, take a look at https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/data-integration
